# Unity 2021.3 can't access Light2D, namespace UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity version **2021.3**, My project was a simple 2d project and after a while I added Universal RP. I configure the renderer and the lights work fine in my editor and game.

I want to get Light2D in my script but I can't get it with any namespace that was suggested.

```
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;
```

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
```

Both namespaces shows error that **Universal** is missing (can't find).

I checked and Universal RP is updated to the last version, I tried restart unity and regenerate the files.
I even thought maybe I need add this in the code assembly but also could not find any of the namespaces there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, Added all RenderPipeline.Universal... references to my code assembly.
I'm not sure which one of them exactly needed but I just added them all in case.

[Photo of my code assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xyru.png)

Comment: When Creating an Assembly definition, the respective assembly should be added. Like Unity InputSystem, Cinemachine, etc. Also, mark your question as accepted by clicking on the tick.